# Log4Net Not Logging When Deployed

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

Using version `1.2.11`. Logging works on my dev machine, but won't create the directory or log when deployed.

I tried:

- giving full directory access to IUSR, Everyone, local users.
- running the app pool as a local admin account.
- to use internal debugging as [Phil Haack describes here](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx).

Stopped and started the app pool after each change.

Nothing is produced in the output file.

My log4Net config is below.  Any thoughts on what to try next?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log4net debug="true">
  <appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="..\Logging\log.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
    <threshold value="DEBUG" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] &lt;%X{auth}&gt; - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Is the output directory or file created?

Comment: No, neither is created.

Comment: In code, are you setting up Log4Net to use XML configuration? Should be using the `XmlConfigurator` class somewhere.

Comment: I neglected to add that, but oddly logging still works on my development machine.  Would it make sense that it works in dev without this, but needs it when deployed?

Comment: It might be hiding in the `AssemblyInfo.cs`.  Are you perhaps switching `AssemblyInfo.cs` when packaging?  Also, I'm not sure if building for debug or release might effect it.

Comment: Hmm, no it's not referenced anywhere.  Maybe I'll post something in their forum.

Comment: @DavinTryon post that as an answer, as I was in fact not calling it.  Still don't know why it works when debugging!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the directory and the file is not being created, then most likely, the configuration is not being read (and therefore used) at runtime.

I always forget to add the single line of code for Log4net that hooks up the configuration.  This code usually appears in the bootstrap class in the application (e.g. Global.asax for an ASP.NET app).

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(configFile));  // configFile being the path to the file.
```

Instead of the above in-line, you can add this attribute to the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

Either way, this will wire up log4net.  More information is found in the [Manual Configuration section of the log4net docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html).

Comment: I'm not sure how this explains him being able to log when he's in a development environment.

Comment: I was beating my head against the wall on this one for a while. I tried using the AssemblyInfo.cs method, and that worked on my local dev box but not on the server. Once I added the line `XmlConfigurator.Configure();` to the Global.asax.cs file, it worked!

Comment: Same as @JebaDaHut - It was working on my dev machine using the AssemblyInfo.cs line, but not when deployed.  After adding `XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(....))` did it begin logging on my deployment servers.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using IIS, make sure the correct group has modify access to the Logs folder (usually IIS_USERS).

Comment: This fixed my issue.  But I only gave IIS_USRS read and write access (not execute).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a permissions issue to me.  I almost always use a directory where I don't have to enable any special permissions for the applications to write the log files to.

Here is what I generally use with log4net:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="${ALLUSERSPROFILE}/<Company Name>/Logs/<Program Name>/<Log file name>.txt" />
```

Of cource you'll need to substitute Company Name, Program Name and Log file name in the above with actual values.

This will write to the ProgramData folder where access is typically not restricted.  You can navigate to this folder in File Explorer by typing %ProgramData% or %AllUsersProfile%

Another thing I like about this method is that it works on nearly every microsoft O/S.  XP, Vista, 7, 8

Answer (score 2):

You probably do not know where you are logging:

```
<file value="..\Logging\log.txt" />
```

Will is derived from your running directory, which is iis its directory. You can better use a full path like:

```
<file value="c:\Logging\log.txt" />
```

Then you can give the right access rights to the logging directory. Log4net will not create any directories as far as I know. So you have to create the c:\logging directory first.

Answer (score 1):

Non of the answers worked for me until I put these lines to the web.config app settings:

```
<add key="log4net.Config" value="Log.config" />
<add key="log4net.Config.Watch" value="True" />
```